# Constraint Violation Exception In Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting constraint violation exception on specific primary key when committing.

I have a base table which stores logs. Also I have a IP Table which stores IP details of log. This IP table have one to many relationship to log table.

When I commit first time it works perfectly. And then re-ran my code check the integrity of constraints. It works well if I omit the record which has IP table ID of below. If I try to insert the record which has this IP ID (UUID Calculated By IP Address Value to ensure unique IP is inserted) I'm getting constraint violation exception.

> **73B0AFE5-A54D-3130-868E-A5D2040A8A20** (UUID of specific IP)

---

Here error thrown when executing above record

> ERROR : Duplicate entry 'UUID bin val' for key 1
>
> ExceptionMapperStandardImpl - HHH000346: Error during managed flush
>   [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement]

Here is my base table implementatation

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOG")
public class LOG_Y18 implements LogEntity {
    private UUID logId;
    private Date LOG_TIME;
    private String URL;
    private LOGIP logip;

    public LOG_Y18() {
        this.logId = UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    public LOG_Y18(Date LOG_TIME, String URL, LOGIP logip) {
        this.logId = UUID.randomUUID();
        this.LOG_TIME = LOG_TIME;
        this.URL = URL;
        this.logip = logip;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "LOGID", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    public UUID getLogId() {
        return logId;
    }

    public void setLogId(UUID logId) {
        this.logId = logId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "LOG_TIME")
    public Date getLOG_TIME() {
        return LOG_TIME;
    }

    public void setLOG_TIME(Date LOG_TIME) {
        this.LOG_TIME = LOG_TIME;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "URL", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    public String getURL() {
        return URL;
    }

    public void setURL(String URL) {
        this.URL = URL;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public LOGIP getLogip() {
        return logip;
    }

    public void setLogip(LOGIP logip) {
        this.logip = logip;
    }

}
```

Here is my one to many relationship to above entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOG_IP", indexes = @Index(columnList = "IP"))
public class LOGIP {
    private UUID ID;
    private Long IP;
    private String COUNTRY;

    public LOGIP() {
    }

    public LOGIP(Long IP, String COUNTRY) {
        this.ID = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(String.valueOf(IP).getBytes());
        this.IP = IP;
        this.COUNTRY = COUNTRY;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)", nullable = false)
    public UUID getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(UUID ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "IP")
    public Long getIP() {
        return IP;
    }

    public void setIP(Long IP) {
        this.IP = IP;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "COUNTRY")
    public String getCOUNTRY() {
        return COUNTRY;
    }

    public void setCOUNTRY(String COUNTRY) {
        this.COUNTRY = COUNTRY;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, i understood the problem as follows: you commit an IP entry once and it works. Then you commit an IP entry with the same UUID as the first one, and this fails? Is this your problem?

Comment: No, I have tested with 1000 log records which has 200 unique ip addresses. Upon first commit the log table has 1000 entries and 200 ip in iptable. If I re run this it works untill above mentioned id. Then I checked my log table which has some 1400 some entries[log table I&amp;#39;d generated randomly. So inserting duplicate records with random id]. Iptable has same 200 entries. So the problem is when the ip id is above mentioned hibernate tries to insert that record again instead of using record which will be already there in the iptable.

Comment: I have also checked this by catching exception and creating session again for other records to commit. Of 1000 records only 2 them is not committed due to this error.

Comment: With which method(s) do you persist your entries? e.g `save()`, `persist()`, `merge()`?

Comment: with save() and then commit() after that I have evicted entities

Comment: according to the object states, `save()` is mabye not the best choice. It would be better to work with `persist()` and `merge()`. Here is some more explanation about that: http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-save-persist-update-merge-saveorupdate Hope this helps.

Comment: used merge(), saveOrUpdate() all seems to throw same exception

Comment: how are you generating the random UUID, is it possible that you might end up with the same log entry UUID. If yes than you will have this constraint violation exception due to  duplicate entry in the `JOIN Table LOG_LOG_IP`, which you can find by looking up the database.